# Prove that for every natural number $n > 2$ there is a prime number between $n$ and $n!$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So I have already read this page with the solution:

[For all $n>2$ there exists a prime number between $n$ and $ n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084296/for-all-n2-there-exists-a-prime-number-between-n-and-n)

Now I was able to reason that $p < n!$ Because I was given the hint that $(n! - 1)$ has a prime divisor. But I am still a little hazy on the reasoning provided why $n < p$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A (prime) divisor of $n!-1$ can't be a divisor of $n!$ (if it were, it would divide $1$). Furthermore $n!$ is divisible by all of $1, 2, \ldots n$.

Comment: Ok i think i see it. Are we kinda appealing to the same idea used in the "no largest prime proof", where since $(n! - 1)$ has a prime divisor it cannot be any of the $n! $ terms because that woukd produce a remainder so then it means our prime divisor has to be larger than n?

Comment: @dc3rd Yes, that's very similar.

Answer (score 1):

From Bertrand's postulate , there exist always a prime number between $n$ and $2n$ but for $n>1$, $n!>2n$

Comment: Appealing to powerful theorems defeats the purpose of the exercise.

Comment: I should mention i don't know bertrand's