# For all n > 2, prove there exists a prime $ p$ such that $ n < p < n! $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How would I go about proving this? I do not understand the $ p | n! $ and $ p | n! -1 $ approach ... which I have found on previous posts.

Comment: This was asked almost 3 years ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1084296/for-all-n2-there-exists-a-prime-number-between-n-and-n

Answer (score 3):

Since $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot ...\cdot n$, we know that every number from $2$ to $n$ divides $n!$.

This means that if we subtract $1$ from $n!$, then the result is *not* divisible by any number from $2$ to $n$.

So, any prime factor of $n!-1$ has to be larger than $n$ ... but of course smaller than $n!$.

Comment: Right! This is a (perhaps simpler) variation of Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many primes.