# For all natural numbers, there exists a prime in between n and n! (n<p<n!)

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

Is there a way to prove this without using Bertrand's postulate?

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Aside from the fact that this claim is not true for $n=1$ ... this very question was asked and answered just a few days ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486809/for-all-n-2-prove-there-exists-a-prime-p-such-that-n-p-n/2486815#2486815

Comment: @Bram28 , regarding the comment you made in the post you linked, would it also be right if I subtracted n! by 2, (n!-2)? Also, is there a proof behind this rule

Comment: @ChinoMalaharis No, when you subtract $2$, then the result is divisible by $2$ ... you want to pick $n!-1$, because that one will have to have prime factors greater than $n$.

Comment: @Bram28 So just to clarify, the only numbers that would be divisible by n!-1 would be the n!-1 and 1, making it a prime?

Comment: @ChinoMalaharis No, that's not true. For example, $5!-1=119$ is not prime .. but its prime factors $7$ and $17$ are greater than $5$. So, in general, either $n!-1$ is prime itself, or it is not, but if it is not, its prime factors are still greater than $n$ (and of course smaller than $n!$

Comment: @Bram28 I see... how would you prove that the prime factors of n!-1 are still greater than n in a general term?

Comment: @ChinoMalaharis SInce $n!$ is divisble by $2$, the number *right before* it, $n!-1$ is not. same for $3$, $4$, etc. all the way up and including $n$. So we know that $n!-1$ is *definitely* not divisible by any numbers from $2$ to $n$ ... so whatever numbers divide $n!-1$, they would have to be grater than $n$, excluding  $1$ Of course, but $1$ is not a prime... or in other words: any prime divisor (or prime factor) *has to be* greater than $n$.

Comment: @Bram28 Ah ok.. and how would you know that the factors of n!-1 are prime? Sorry for asking you so many questions, I just wanna make sure I know this proof well.

Comment: Nvm, you don't have to asnwer. I've figured it out. Thank you so much for the help.

Comment: @ChinoMalaharis You're welcome! :)